# how to get rid of duplicates through query?

Tags: html, mysql, sql, statements

so this is my current code which runs the sql statement:

```
   $sql= "SELECT * FROM contractor WHERE CONCAT( FIRSTNAME,' ', LASTNAME,' ', ARRIVAL,' ', ID, ' ', DRIVERL ) like '%$searchTerm%' GROUP BY DRIVERL";


        $query = mysql_query($sql);

    $count=mysql_num_rows($query);

    if(($count)>=1)
    {
    $output = "";

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))


    {


            $output .= '<a  href="'.'http://localhost/contractor/redirectcontractorpage.php'.'?userid='.$row['id'].'">
     First Name: '.$row['FIRSTNAME'].'<br />
            Last Name: '.$row['LASTNAME'].'<br />
            Arrival: '.$row['ARRIVAL'].'<br />
            DL: '.$row['DRIVERL'].'<br />
            Company: '.$row['COMPANY'].'<br /><br /></a>';



  }


echo $output;

    }

    else
    echo "There was no matching record for the name " . $searchTerm;

}
```

for example I am printing all the results for the name joe. 
First Name: calvin
Last Name: joe
Arrival: 2014-06-24 14:20:07
DL: kahisds8687
Company: aerotek

First Name: calvin
Last Name: joe
Arrival: 2014-06-24 14:09:24
DL: kahisds8687
Company: aerotek

First Name: calvin
Last Name: joe
Arrival: 2014-06-24 14:07:02
DL: kahisds8687
Company: aerotek

First Name: joe
Last Name: aef
Arrival: 2014-06-24 14:46:34
DL: jior21r3
Company: asfsad

First Name: calvin
Last Name: joe
Arrival: 2014-06-24 14:04:13
DL: kahisds8687
Company: aerotek

instead I want to print the names based on the duplicate dl's incase the names are the same. so what should i do to tweak the sql query, I tried using distinct but am getting errors.

---

UPDATE: 
So I am looking to query in a table. I would like to print every joe there is, even if the first and last name is the same ( or isnt ) but solely based on driverL #. So if there is a Joe Smith and a Joe James and I search for joe, all the records of each  ( which can be many because they can be incoming and out going ) can be present. i would like to just print one of each, doesnt matter if its the earliest or latest arrival date, thats not what im worried about. I am more trying to print just one case of each so i can then continue in my application with the correct individual. also this way currently i would be printing all cases ( which can be a ton if they have been entered many times in the past month for example ) . so i really want to print based on driverL and of course relate to the searchterm depending on what is searched.

First Name: calvin
Last Name: joe
Arrival: 2014-06-24 14:20:07
DL: kahisds8687
Company: aerotek

First Name: calvin
Last Name: joe
Arrival: 2014-06-24 14:09:24
DL: kahisds8687
Company: aerotek

First Name: calvin
Last Name: joe
Arrival: 2014-06-24 14:07:02
DL: kahisds8687
Company: aerotek

First Name: joe
Last Name: aef
Arrival: 2014-06-24 14:46:34
DL: jior21r3
Company:

First Name: calvin
Last Name: joe
Arrival: 2014-06-24 14:04:13
DL: kahisds8687
Company: aerotek

current statement : $sql= "SELECT * FROM contractor WHERE CONCAT( FIRSTNAME,' ', LASTNAME,' ', ARRIVAL, ' ', ID, ' ', DRIVERL ) like '%$searchTerm%' GROUP BY DRIVERL";

i would like just one of each person to be printed so ideally :

First Name: joe
Last Name: aef
Arrival: 2014-06-24 14:46:34
DL: jior21r3
Company:

First Name: calvin
Last Name: joe
Arrival: 2014-06-24 14:04:13
DL: kahisds8687
Company: aerotek

Comment: point of order: potential for sql injection, and query above will create full table scan as you are concat'ing the fields together.

Comment: Your code is already returning the list of distinct entries.  If you only want to show "Calvin Joe" once - then you need to use distinct at the front of the query, and get rid of the arrival time in your result set.

Answer (score 0):

Right now sql does not see all of the calvin joe entries as duplicates. This is because there is at least one field that is different between the different results. In this case, that is the arrival value. The first calvin joe has `2014-06-24 14:20:07` stored as the arrival, whereas the second calvin joe has `2014-06-24 14:09:24`. The seconds are different and sql is never going to look at them the same. There are several ways to get around this problem.

The first way to solve this issue is if the time does not matter. Then, you can use

```
Select distinct firstname, 
                lastname, 
                cast(arrival as date), 
                dl, 
                company
From ...
```

What this does is tell sql that only the date part of arrival should be used. Then, sql only selects the data points where at least one of the column values is different than the other data that is being included. In this case, it will convert all of the arrivals for all of the calvin joes to 2014-06-24. Then calvin joe will only be selected once.

Lets say for a minute that your data was about plane flights. Maybe you do need a time listed. In this case, you need to determine how you want to select that time. Maybe you want the earliest time to show up, maybe you want the latest time to show up. In this next example, I am going to have the latest time show up.

```
Select  firstname, 
        lastname, 
        max(arrival), 
        dl, 
        company
FROM contractor 
WHERE CONCAT( FIRSTNAME,' ', LASTNAME,' ', ARRIVAL,' ', ID, ' ', DRIVERL ) like '%$searchTerm%' 

GROUP BY firstname,
         lastname,
         dl,
         company
```

This query tells sql that we want all the data points that have the same first name, last name, dl, and company to be shown as one data point. Then, sql looks at all of the arrivals and picks the one that has the greatest time to show to the user. This is called an aggregate function. This query will only show calvin joe once and will pick `2014-06-24 14:20:07` as the arrival value.

Comment: appreciate the help :) but im still having a problem/concern. so I tried the first case and I am getting errors dealing with ' Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\contractor\searchpage.php on line 69 ' ALSO I am trying to use the driver license to distinguish between two individuals with the same first or last name if thats what they search by. and i have all the cases printing from the table of the particular name, where i really would just like one of each particular person. so really just one calvin joe and joe aef.hope that makes sense

Comment: @user3711444 I don't quite understand. Can you update your question to include this problem?

Can you try the query without the arrival in the select at all and see if you get the error? So 'Select distinct firstname, lastname, dl, company from ...'

Comment: @user3711444 okay, so did you try to run your query except with my select? 'select distinct firstname, lastname, cast(arrival as date), dl, company' and if that didn't work then did you try the same thing without cast(arrival as date)?

Comment: neither works. the issue is constantly rising where the id is being set of the user. this may be a never ending problem :/ its the rest of my code thats not letting the changes work properly. i may have to rethink the code from the beginning.

Comment: i believe the issue is how i am using the query to post the results. its not built for this exact functionality.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. I would recommend working on the sql and the javascript separately. Try to get a sql query that returns the results that you are looking for. Then, see what issues are coming up. It sounds like the current error you are getting is originating in the javascript?